# Get file version from .exe URL-Source in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, chocolatey, appveyor

I know how to get productversion of a file on my windows PC with powershell
(get-item -Path

```bsh
'(get-item -Path 'C:\test.exe').VersionInfo.ProductVersion
```

but is it also possible to get the productversion from a exe file with it's URL?

```bsh
(get-item -Path 'example.com/test.exe').VersionInfo.ProductVersion
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to get the product version from a URL.
When we use a URL it is not the direct path to access the storage server. Therefore we can not determine the version. By C path we can not access the URL Path.

I tried the shell command for Teamviewer setup URL [Teamviewer version 9.X](https://download.teamviewer.com/download/version_9x/TeamViewer_Setup.exe). It is not possible to get it through the URL.

```
PS C:\Users\israr ahmad> (get-item -Path 'download.teamviewer.com/full').VersionInfo.ProductVersion
get-item : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\israr ahmad\download.teamviewer.com\full' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:2
+ (get-item -Path 'download.teamviewer.com/full').VersionInfo.ProductVe ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\israr ...viewer.com\full:String) [Get-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand

PS C:\Users\israr ahmad> ^C
PS C:\Users\israr ahmad> https://download.teamviewer.com/download/version_9x/TeamViewer_Setup.exe

+  (get-item -Path 'https://www.teamviewer.com/download/version_9x/Team ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (https:String) [Get-Item], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand

PS C:\Users\israr ahmad>  (get-item -Path '../www.teamviewer.com/download/version_9x/TeamViewer_Setup.exe').VersionInfo.ProductVersion
get-item : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\www.teamviewer.com\download\version_9x\TeamViewer_Setup.exe' because it does not exist.
```